# Google App Engine java blobstore service with spring

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, blobstore, spring-transactions

I am using spring mvc and transactions in GAE. I am also using blobstore service to upload files. After blobstore dispatches to my controller, it doesn't have transactions enabled and when i access services it started throwing error. The same controller and service works fine without blobstore.

```
WARNING: /_ah/upload/aghlZmxvd2FwcHIbCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGD4M
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Impossible to perform operation since it either requires an active transaction or 'NontransactionalRead' enabled. You have neither of these.
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:264)
at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:179)
at com.test.comp.dao.impl.UserDao.findByEmail(UserDao.java:21)
at com.test.comp.service.impl.UserService.findByEmail(UserService.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:104)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy32.findByEmail(Unknown Source)
at com.test.comp.controller.TestController.saveTest(TestController.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:384)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:111)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.TransactionNotReadableException: Impossible to perform operation since it either requires an active transaction or 'NontransactionalRead' enabled. You have neither of these.
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1395)
at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:163)
... 82 more
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418) ~[na:na]
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) ~[na:na]
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) ~[na:na]
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409) ~[appengine-tools-sdk-1.6.1.jar:na]
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.TransactionNotReadableException: Impossible to perform operation since it either requires an active transaction or 'NontransactionalRead' enabled. You have neither of these.
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1395) ~[datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar:na]
at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:163) ~[datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar:na]
... 82 common frames omitted
Mar 29, 2012 5:30:29 AM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$PersistDatastore persist
```

UploadBlobServlet is actually dispatching the request in the below way. 
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(successPath).forward(wrappedRequest, resp);
Does the request dispatcher has anything to do with transactions.

Thanks,
Ramesh.V